# Active Directory LDAP for commercial ZF2 Apps - Licensing?

Tags: php, active-directory, zend-framework2, ldap, openldap

I want to use MS AD LDAP (via Win 2k12R2) for my commercial SaaS Zend Framework 2 Applications. It should be the RBAC backend for my logins.

1. Is this allowed? Do I need licenses to do this?
2. As my second choice - What about OpenLDAP? Licensing, etc.?

Atm I use a MySQL Backend but LDAP is a better choice for professional RBAC.

I'm open for other suggestions too, just drop in your opinions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal agreements, not software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider supporting multiple directory services, to allow the end user to decide which directory service they would prefer to use.

If by SaaS you mean that you will host all ID's then you would be responsible for licensing costs and it would probably be best to use a free to cheaper directory service and be done with it.

Comment: okay, so you would prefer openldap? You are right, the application is a payed online service, ldap is my alternative to usermanagement via MySQL tables.

Comment: Whatever you are comfortable with.  Lots of free to cheap options. Obviously any license costs go against your overhead.